# GAS/ Javascript giving wrong figures when summing up numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, math, google-apps-script

My Javascript/GAS code uses the user ID to call for time entries via API for a specific date range (1 week) and sum up the hours. These time entries are saved in an array and then summed up. The first 50 additions on the log are correct but as you go through the list you realize wrong summed figures and long decimal places. What could be wrong and what can I do to solve this. Here is my code:

```
var TKF_URL = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/';
var TKF_AUTH = 'auth'
var TKF_PGSZ = 2500
var from = '2020-01-06'
var to = '2020-01-22'
var options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + TKF_AUTH
    }
};

function getUsers() {
    var userarray = [];
    var lastpage = false;
    var page = 1;
    do {

        // gets 10kft data   
        var users = read10k_users(page);

        // writes data from current page to array   
        for (var i in users.data) {
            var rec = {};

            // pushing of mandatory data     
            rec.id = users.data[i].id;
            rec.display_name = users.data[i].display_name;
            rec.email = users.data[i].email;
            userarray.push(rec);
        }

        // checks if this is the last page (indicated by paging next page link beeing null   
        if (users.paging.next != null) {
            lastpage = false;
            var page = page + 1;
        } else {
            lastpage = true;
        }
    }
    while (lastpage == false);
    return (userarray);


    return (userarray);

}

function read10k_users(page) {

    var endpoint = 'users?';

    var url = TKF_URL + endpoint + 'per_page=' + TKF_PGSZ + '&auth=' + TKF_AUTH + '&page=' + page;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var json = JSON.parse(response);

    //Logger.log(json.data)
    return (json);
}


function showTimeData() {

    var users = getUsers()
    var endpoint = 'users/';
    var time_array = [];



    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

        var total_hours = 0;

        // Logger.log(users[i].id)
        var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + users[i].id + '/time_entries?fields=approvals' + '&from=' + from + '&to=' + to + '&auth=' + TKF_AUTH;
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

        var info = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

        var content = info.data;

        for (var j = 0; j < content.length; j++) {

            total_hours += content[j].hours;

            //     }
            //     
            //       if(total_hours < 35){
            //    
            //          sendMail(user[i]);
            //      
            //       }

            Logger.log('User name: ' + users[i].display_name + ' ' + 'User id: ' + users[i].id + '  ' + 'total hours: ' + total_hours)



        }

    }

    function sendMail(user) {



        var emailAddress = user.email;
        var message = 'Dear ' + user.display_name + 'Your timesheets is incomplete , please visist 10k Ft and commlete your timesheet'
        var subject = 'TimeSheet';

        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

    }
}
```

Log results

[image]

Comment: You have `total_hours` declared outside of your loop. So what you are doing is calculating the total hours all workers combined, not total hours per worker. Either move the declaration of `total_hours ` to inside the loop, or set it to zero at the top of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `total_hours` declared outside of your loop. So what you are doing is calculating the total hours all workers combined, not total hours per worker.

(removed a lot of code to show only the important parts for your bug)

```
function showTimeData() {
  var users = getUsers()
  var total_hours = 0; // you declare the variable here

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var content = info.data;

    // Calculate the sum for current user
    for (var j = 0; j < content.length; j++) {    
      total_hours += content[j].hours;    
    }

    // Check if total_hours for ALL workers is less than 35 
    if (total_hours < 35) sendMail(user[i]);

    // total_hours is not reset, so the sum is used in next iteration.
  }
}
```

Move the declaration of `total_hours` to inside the loop, or reset it to zero.

```
function showTimeData() {  
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var total_hours = 0; // you declare the variable here
  }
}
```

Your loop should look something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var total_hours = 0;

  var url = "https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/" + users[i].id + "/time_entries?fields=approvals" + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to + "&auth=" + TKF_AUTH;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  var info = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  var content = info.data;

  for (var j = 0; j < content.length; j++) {
    total_hours += content[j].hours;
  }

  if (total_hours < 35) {
    sendMail(user[i]);
  }

  Logger.log("User name: " + users[i].display_name + " " + "User id: " + users[i].id + "  " + "total hours: " + total_hours);
}
```

Comment: Hey @some , thanks for taking the time to look at the code. I have actually moved the  total_hours declaration inside the loop, but this time I get fewer hours for the date range. I have edited my code to include the complete code from start to end so that you may look at it and advise. I will really appreciate your advice on this. How do I also reset the total_hours variable?

Comment: @levi You moved into the inner loop, but you should have it in the outer loop: `for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { var total_hours = 0; ...`

Comment: @levi And in function getUsers, you have a for-loop with a global variable: `for (i in users.data)`. Change that to `for (var i in users.data)`.

Comment: I have actually incorporated your suggestion in the edited question and now log shows each user with a series of total hours where each line is added to the previous. Kindly look at the screenshot in the question. If I could get the final figure at the bottom in a single line  with the user ID it will be best

Comment: @levi The inner loop should only be `for (var j = 0; j < content.length; j++) { total_hours += content[j].hours;}` The check for sending an email and the logging should be outside of that loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206635/discussion-between-levi-and-some).